# Android layout geting right to left instead of left to right

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing a strange issue. I designed layout from Left to Right, but in some devices its showing Right to Left.
In Moto X : this is right arrow direction >>
[image]

In Samsung s7 : look at arrow direction, it get reverse.
[image]

Please suggest, what should be reason for this. Its also happening with other views.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that it is linked to rtl support. If you device uses arabic language(or any other right to left languages) it will mirror some elements.

If you'd like to disable this try this in your manifest:

```
<application
    ...
    android:supportsRtl="false">
...
</application>
```